# Convert UTF-8 character to xmodmap name

Tags: xmodmap

Is there a way of converting a UTF-8 character to its corresponding `xmodmap` name?

So if the input is `”` the output would be `rightdoublequotemark`.

Comment: Looks like the info you want is in here: http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/data/unicode.txt

Comment: @slm No I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man xmodmap` says:

> The list of keysym names may be found in the header file <X11/keysymdef.h> (without the XK_ prefix), supplemented by the keysym database /usr/local/share/X11/XKeysymDB.

For your example, the corresponding line of X11/keysymdef.h is:

```
 #define XK_rightdoublequotemark          0x0ad3  /* U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK */
```

Recent versions of this file has comment header that describes how to parse it reliably using `Perl`/etc. for any needed machine action, including making reverse table.